# Is a TextIOWrapper object automatically closed if it is not saved to a variable?

Tags: python, file, bytecode

I generally like to use the `with open(...) as file:` idiom for opening files because it avoids failing to close a file, improves code readability, and improves exception handling. However, I have seen other people's code use one-liners to open and read/write a file without saving the `TextIOWrapper` object:

```
# Read a file
contents = open('the_file.txt').read()

# Write to a file
open('the_file.txt', 'w').write('This is the thing.')

# Write an empty file
open('empty_file.txt', 'w')
```

These idioms are appealing because of their simplicity, but I want to understand what python does with those file objects.

I tried using the `dis` module to inspect the bytecode, but I'm not sure how to read the output:

```
def myfunc():
    open('test.txt', 'w')
dis.dis(myfunc)
```

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (open)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test.txt')
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('w')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
def withfunc():
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        pass
dis.dis(withfunc)
```

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (open)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test.txt')
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('w')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 SETUP_WITH               6 (to 16)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (f)

  3          12 POP_BLOCK
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
        >>   16 WITH_CLEANUP_START
             18 WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
             20 END_FINALLY
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
def savefunc():
    f = open('test.txt', 'w')
    f.close()
dis.dis(savefunc)
```

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (open)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test.txt')
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('w')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (f)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (f)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (close)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             16 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

I have two questions:

1. What happens under the hood when you use `open` without saving the TextIOWrapper object (especially regarding whether they are properly closed)
2. Are there reasons to NOT use the one-liners?

Comment: `dis` isn't going to really help you here, you have to know the implementations of the objects themselves

Comment: Never `open()` without referencing the obj.  The object remains in memory and cannot be freed since you don't reference to `close()` with.

Comment: @Idlehands that's not true. it will be freed (in CPython), and closed, but the output buffer won't necessarily write to disk. Well, actually, that only happens if you *do* have a reference around, because CPython doesn't guarantee that `__del__` will be called for objects that still have references when the interpreter shuts down.

Comment: You should always just use a context-manager.